# Rails find_by new column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am new to rails ,

I have added a new column “control_id” in a table users and same is added in model file under

`attr_accessible :control_id`

But when I use find_by_control_id(1) . I am getting undefined method error . Do I need to add the column any where else ?

code :

`search_id = User.find_by_control_id(1).id`

in the webhook i will get control_id , i need to use the control_id to find the id in users table

Thanks

Comment: What version of Rails you are using?

Comment: `attr_accessible` has nothing to do with finders or declaring attributes - its an old and depreciated way of doing mass assignment protection.  ActiveRecord generates dynamic finders based on the database schema.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's no `user` with `control_id` 1 present in your DB, that's why it's thowing `undefined method id for nilClass` error. You need to handle it in some way in your controller, like I am redirecting to root_path incase the query returns `nil`.

```
search_id = User.find_by_control_id(1).try(:id)
redirect_to root_path if search_id.nil?
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I am using rails 3.2 , find_by(control_id: 1) is also throwing undefined method error

Comment: is there a way to use find_by_column_name?

Comment: Can you add code to show the full query you are writing?

Comment: added the code , i need to find the id using the control_id , then i will add the output id in another table

Comment: @Eswar it looks like there's no user with that particular `control_id` is present in DB. You need to handle it in the code. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Wondering if where would work?

```
User.where(control_id: 3)
```

or

```
User.find_by(control_id: params[:control_id])
```

i.e `User.find_by(control_id: 3)`

You can always do `user = User`  then `pp user.methods` This will show you all the available methods.